# Why is gravity sensitive to absolute energies?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, energy, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In QFT absolute energies play no role in the physical set-up, only relative energies (i.e. energy differences) are important. However, in general relativity this doesn't appear to be the case, I've read that gravity is sensitive to absolute energies. I thought this could be argued by considering the $T_{00}$ component in the stress-energy tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$, i.e. the energy density $\rho$. The problem is, absolute quantities such as mass and energy density appear in QFT as well so how does one explain that QFT is *not* sensitive to absolute energies whereas general relativity is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with qft. Imagine taking the action $S$ and adding a constant. The new action is

\begin{equation}
S_{new} = S + M^4 \int d^4 x
\end{equation}
where M is a mass scale needed for dimensions.

This last term in the action does not depend on any fields so it does not contribute to any dynamics. One way to express this is that the only effect of the last term is to change the path integral by an overall constant 
\begin{equation}
Z_{new} = \int D\phi e^{iS + i M^4 \int d^4 x} =\left( e^{i M^4 \int d^4 x} \right) Z
\end{equation}
where $\phi$ is a generic label for all the fields and $Z=\int D\phi e^{iS}$. The overall constant always drops out of correlation functions since they will be things like $Z^{-1} \delta Z/ \delta J$ (or if you like the constant can just be absorbed into the measure of the path integral).

General relativity is diffeomorphism invariant which prevents us from just writing down a constant times $d^4x$. The diff invariant generalization of the above relevant for Gravity is 
\begin{equation}
S_{new,GR} = S + M^4 \int d^4 x \sqrt{-g}
\end{equation}
The factor of $\sqrt{-g}$ changes everything. The "constant" term now depends on the metric, which is a dynamical field. So this term now does contribute to the dynamics.

In path integral terms, the point is that you can't factor $e^{iM^4\int d^4 x \sqrt{-g}}$ outside the path integral because you are integrating over $g_{\mu\nu}$.

Indeed, we usually identify $M^4= M_{pl}^2 \Lambda$ where $M_{pl}$ is the planck scale and $\Lambda$ is the cosmological constant.

To summarize, Gravity sees everything, including constants. If you like, the cosmological constant is an intrinsic energy associated to spacetime ("vacuum energy"). The more spacetime volume you have the more "cosmological constant" energy you have. Since the metric is used to measure volumes, Gravity sees this contribution to the energy.

---

Edit in response to comments below.

A mass term in qft is a term quadratic in the fields with no derivatives. For a scalar field a mass term looks like 
\begin{equation}
S_{mass} = -\frac{1}{2} \int d^4 x m^2 \phi^2
\end{equation}
This is field dependent so it contributes to the dynamics. You can't factor the mass term out of the path integral. The same goes for a more general potential $V(\phi)$.

Indeed on some level you can think of the cosmological constant as being like a potential for Gravity. Writing $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu}/M_{pl}$ the cc term can be expanded in powers of $h$
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{-g} \sim 1 + h/M_{pl} + h^2/M_{pl}^2 + \cdots
\end{equation}
where all the coefficients in this "potential for $h$" are fixed by diff invariance. I wouldn't take this analogy too seriously, but it's a way you can look at it.

Finally, it was asked if one could say Gravity sees the cc because of diff invariance. I would say that is indeed a valid way of looking at things based on the argument above.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thanks. I have a couple of questions though: So is the reason why gravity is sensitive to absolute energies simply a result of the diffeomorphism invariance of the theory then? For the QFT, what about any energy terms contained in the original action $S$? Is it simply that in flat space mass terms are non-dynamical and thus physically irrelevant?

Comment: I'll update the answer to comment on these things, but what do you mean by "energy terms in the original action?" Do you mean constant terms in S, or mass terms, or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I meant things like mass terms.

Comment: Updated the answer to address these questions.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be correct to say that Gravity is sensitive to absolute energy before even considering vacuum energy (as the equivalence principle argues that all forms of matter and (mass and energy) should gravitate in the same way - if only energy differences had gravitational effects then rest mass certainly wouldn't gravitate (as it is absolute), at least according to GR)?

Comment: To be honest I'm not really sure what you mean by the statement "if only energy differences had gravitational effects then rest mass certainly wouldn't gravitate." I wouldn't try to make statements about hypothetical versions of gravity (unless you have a specific model in mind). The statement "gravity is sensitive to the value of the energy, not just to energy differences," is exactly the same statement as "vacuum energy gravitates," which is the point I was making in my answer. Mass terms are physical even without gravity because they field dependent.

Comment: My issue is that in a piece of work I was trying to argue that the vacuum energy gravitates precisely because Gravity is sensitive to absolute energy, which is what seems to be suggested in Carrolls notes: http://preposterousuniverse.com/writings/encyc/  (in "The cosmological constant And vacuum energy" section)

Comment: Sorry, I realise that I was a bit cavalier with that statement about rest mass previously (i.e. incorrect)!

Comment: Right, "gravity is sensitive to absolute energy" and "vacuum energy gravitates" are equivalent statements, that's the point of my answer.

Comment: So is the point that energy is only defined up to an additive constant, which in the context of QFT (where SR is in play) is non-dynamical, i.e. adding this constant term to the action doesn't affect the equations of motion, thus in this context we can redefine the situation such that all energies a measured relative to the vacuum. However, in GR (as you put in your answer) adding a constant term to the action does affect the equations of motion (due to the integration measure $\sqrt{-g}$) and thus must be taken into account in any physical situation?